# How to add watermark Image using MPDF in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

[here is the pdf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWObF.jpg)

I want to add this kind of background image to my PDF using MPDF. But also i want to reduce the background image opacity.

Comment: can i see your code Sir??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
$mpdf->SetWatermarkImage(
  'assets/dist/img/ExampleLogo1.png',
   0.3,                 // this for transparency
   array(x,y),      // Alignment
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For future reference to the people after this code add this:  $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;